# Find minimum sum of elements in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, minimization

Given a matrix, find the **minimum sum** of elements such that element is chosen from each row, and the adjacent element should not come from the same column. Assume the matrix only has 3 columns.

```
example 1:
[[1, 2, 3], 

 [1, 2, 3], 

 [3, 3, 1]]

minimum sum = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4  // matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][2] or matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[2][2]

example 2:
[[1, 100, 1], 

 [2, 99, 30],

 [100, 12, 13]]

minimum sum = 1 + 2 + 12 = 15 // matrix[0][2] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[2][1]

example 3:
[[1, 2, 3], 

 [2, 5, 4],

 [2, 3, 1],

 [1, 6, 3]]

minimum sum = 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6 // matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[2][2] + matrix[3][0]
```

Here's my code:

```
    public static int minCost(List<List<Integer>> matrix) {
        // Write your code here
        int rows = matrix.size();

        int[] cost = findMin(matrix.get(0), -1);
        int total = cost[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
            List<Integer> row = matrix.get(i);
            cost = findMin(row, cost[1]);
            total += cost[0];
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static int[] findMin(List<Integer> row, int col){
        int[] ans = new int[2];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
            if (i == col){
                continue;
            }
            if (row.get(i) < min) {
                min = row.get(i);
                ans[0] = min;
                ans[1] = i;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

I initially approached this question with Greedy, which is to find the minimum element in a row and the column of the element is different from that of the previous element.

This method does not satisfy examples 2 and 3. I think dynamic programming would be the way to approach this problem but I am not sure how to construct the mem part. How to actually solve this problem with dynamic programming? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a problem statement, but what is your question?

Comment: This is a straightforward application of dynamic programming, backtracking, or any of the other available space-traversing methods.  Please post your code and a full problem statement; posting homework (or self-assigned problem) without the expected solution attempt is generally not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the notice. The problem has been updated!

Comment: Where are you stuck with the DP part?  Your state information consists of the sum so far, the current row, and the last column chosen.  You also need to iterate through *all* legal choices for each row (3 for the first row, 2 for rows thereafter).

Comment: @Prune I have trouble identifying the recursive structure. I am not quite sure about how should I construct the memory.

Comment: for the third example, shoulnt the answer be 2+2+1+1=6? Or am i missing sth.?

Comment: @Lecagy My bad. Yes it should be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to identify the recursive structure as you have specified in one of your comments.

You could identify as follows:
Lets say you are currently on a row `row` and the previous column you chose was `prevcol` then you need to choose a value that is not in the previous column and recurse on the remaining rows and get the minimum of all such values  i.e. each time you choose a column that is not previous column and recurse on remaining rows by specifying the prev column chosen was that column you chose just now.

Look at this recursive equation to understand more:

`f( arr, row, prevcol ) = minimum of ( for all col not equal to prevcol ( arr[row][col] + f( arr, row + 1, col ) )`

you see how to specify the next row and previous column chosen in the call `f(arr, row +1, col )` ?

The base condition is if `row == arr.length` i.e. no rows remaining then result is `0`.

And you memoize the values that you get for each combination of `row` and `prevcol`

Java code would be :

```
private static int f( int[][] arr, int row, int prevCol ) {
    if ( row == arr.length ) return 0;

    int C = arr[row].length;
    if ( dp[row][prevCol+1] != Integer.MAX_VALUE ) return dp[row][prevCol+1];
    int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for ( int j = 0; j < C; j++ ) {
      if ( j != prevCol ) {
        int val = arr[row][j] + f ( arr, row + 1, j );
        res = Math.min ( res, val );
      }
    }
    dp[row][prevCol+1] = res;
    return res;
  }
```

You need to instantiate `dp` array like:

```
dp = new int[arr.length][arr[0].length+1];
for ( int[] r : dp ) Arrays.fill(r, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

and you call the function like:
`f( arr, 0, -1 )` where `0` is the starting `row` and `-1` is the `prevcol`. Because `prevcol` starts with `-1` you need to store the value in `dp[row][prevcol+1]`

and also for your third example the answer is `6` not `9`.

```
row = 0, col = 1 : 2
row = 1, col = 0 : 2
row = 2, col = 2 : 1
row = 3, col = 0 : 1
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @SomeDude
This is my python implementation of the same..

```
import math
def mincost(arr,row,prevcol,n,k):
    if row == len(arr):
        return 0
    C = len(arr[row])
    dp = [[math.inf for x in range(k+1)] for y in range(n)]
    if dp[row][prevcol+1] != math.inf:
        return dp[row][prevcol+1]
    res = math.inf
    for j in range(C):
        if j != prevcol:
            val = arr[row][j] + mincost(arr,row+1,j,n,k)
            res = min(res,val)
    dp[row][prevcol+1] = res
    return res
```

I checked for all the above testcases specifed by @bonus, it works.